# Security exception in Android 4.2.2

Tags: java, android, android-securityexception

I have root android device. I want to download and install another application through my Application. I have the SUPERUSER Application installed on my device.

After downloading complete I am using the following code for Application Installation.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
InputStream es = p.getErrorStream();
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(
            p.getOutputStream());
final String libs = "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib ";
final String[] commands = {libs + "pm install -r " + result,"reboot"
                     };

   for (String command : commands) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, " command : " + command);
    os.writeBytes(command + "\n");
    }

    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, " DataOutputStream.writebytes ");
    os.flush();
```

The above coed is working in Android 4.0. But When i run the same code on Andorid 4.2.2.
I run in to sceurity exception.

java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: broadcast asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS

How can I deal with this exception?

Thanking in an Anticipation,

Regards,

AK

Comment: Add those permissions in your manifest?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS" />
```

Under the root `<manifest>` element in your `AndroidManifest.xml`